# Post to Facebook and Twitter simultaneously Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, social-networking

i'm new to this, i need help coding an app on Xcode posting to Facebook and twitter simultaneously, can anyone help, i've looked at social framework but i want to merge the post button together.

Comment: You cannot do that in xcode. Xcode is not bad as an IDE but it is just that, an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use Facebook and Twitter REST API rather than using the native iOS's social frameworks dialogs.

You don't want to display the native dialogs since you'll be unable to post simultaneously.
Instead you need to create your own dialog which sends requests to the networks using SLRequest.

Comment: Hey, appreciate your answer buddy, Facebook have depreciated the REST API right ? so i would use there graph API?

Comment: Yes, use the Graph API.